# MySQL INNER JOIN two tables where one table contains multiple rows with same id

Tags: mysql, join

I want to get id's from one table depending on multiple rows from another table with same id. The id's has to only be returned if all rows from the other table matches each row request. My table structure looks like this.

```
   
tbl_one 
------------------  
id  companyName 
------------------
1   CompanyOne  
2   CompanyTwo  

tbl_two 
-----------------------------   
id  type        content
-----------------------------
1   zipcode     54321
1   category    Car dealers
2   zipcode     54321
2   category    Supermarkets
```

I have tried with INNER JOIN, but i can't seem to make it work no matter how i try.

```
SELECT 
    tbl_one.id FROM tbl_one 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_two
ON
    tbl_two.id = tbl_one.id 
WHERE
( 
    type = 'zipcode' AND content = '54321'
) 
  AND
( 
    type = 'category' AND content = 'Car dealers' 
)
```

Can anybody answer me what i'm doing wrong with my query? 
Thank you :)

Comment: The middle AND should be an OR - type cannot be zipcode and category at the same time , similar with content.

Comment: The thing is that "type"-column has more than one row with the matching id and therefore can have both "zipcode" and "category" value in it. Since i only want to return the id if both rows are true i need to use AND instead of OR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm.. try this:-

```
/*
drop    table tbl_one;
drop    table   tbl_two;

create  table tbl_one(id int, companyName varchar(20)) ;
Insert into tbl_one values
(1,  'CompanyOne'), 
(2,  'CompanyTwo')  ;

create  table tbl_two(id int,type varchar(20), content varchar(20));
insert into tbl_two values
(1 ,  'zipcode'  ,   '54321'),
(1 ,  'category' ,   'Car dealers'),
(2 ,  'zipcode'  ,   '54321'),
(2 ,  'category' ,   'Supermarkets');
*/
SELECT t1.*
FROM  tbl_one t1
WHERE t1.id in (select t2.id from tbl_two t2 where t2.id = t1.id and t2.type = 'zipcode' AND t2.content = '54321')
and     t1.id in (select t3.id from tbl_two t3 where t3.id = t1.id and t3.type = 'category' AND t3.content = 'Car dealers')
```

Comment: Thanks :) This seems to work for me. I hope it will also work on large tables. Right now i'm dealing with a +10 million records, but so far i seems to do the job very fast.

Answer (score 1):

The query you provided doesn't work because tbl_two.type cannot equal "zipcode" and "category" at the same time. [Perhaps this is what you meant?](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/761f7/1) Note the `OR` operator on line 7, as opposed to your use of `AND`...

```
SELECT one.id
FROM tbl_one one
JOIN tbl_two two
ON   two.id = one.id
WHERE
     two.type = "zipcode" AND two.content = "54321"
OR   two.type = "category" AND two.content = "car dealers"
```

OR perhaps you want to find all of the car dealers in 54321, in which case you would need two joins...

```
SELECT one.id
FROM tbl_one one
JOIN tbl_two one_zip
ON   one_zip.id = one.id
AND  one_zip.type = "zipcode"
AND  one_zip.content = "54321"
JOIN tbl_two one_cat
ON   one_cat.id = one.id
AND  one_cat.type = "category"
AND  one_cat.content = "car dealers"
```

Comment: Second query does what he wants, first no

Comment: The second query does the job. I guess it will come down to a performance test between your and P.Salmon answer